# $ f(x,y)=\sqrt{|xy|} $ . Is $f$ totally differentiable at $(x,y)=(0,0)$?

Tags: real-analysis

$
f(x,y)=\sqrt{|xy|}
$
.

Is $f$ totally differentiable at $(x,y)=(0,0)$
?

I am trying to prove that $f$ is totaly defferentiable:

$$
\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)} \frac{f(0+h,0+k)-(f(0,0)+0\cdot k+0\cdot h)}{||(h,k)||}
=\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)} \sqrt{\frac{|hk|}{h^2+k^2}}
~~~~~~~~(=0????)
$$

I don't have any idea to show that it converges to zero.
Could you give me a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the function is differentiable?

Comment: Now I am not sure.

Comment: Try proving that the limit does not exist by taking $h=\lambda k$

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your limit does not exist. For $h=t$ and $k=0$ it is:
$$\lim_{t\to0} \sqrt{\frac{|hk|}{h^2+k^2}} =
\lim_{t\to0}\sqrt{\frac{0}{t^2}}=0$$
And for $h=t$ and $k=t$ it is:
$$\lim_{t\to0} \sqrt{\frac{|hk|}{h^2+k^2}} =
\lim_{t\to0}\sqrt{\frac{|t^2|}{2t^2}}=\sqrt2$$
Therefore your function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!